# DisplayAttribute doesn't localize its properties in model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, localization, attributes

I use MVVM pattern in my WPF application, and I apply DisplayAttribute with localization to properties of my model:

```cs
class MyModel
{
    [Display(
        ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Strings),
        Name = "MyPropertyName",
        Description = "MyPropertyDescription")]
    public double MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I want to show localized attribute properties of the model property. The necessary resource file is located in the proper place, the necessary culture is set. I also set the Build Action as Embedded Resource, and Custom Tool as PublicResXFileCodeGenerator - as required for DisplayAttribute. But DisplayAttribute returns "MyPropertyName" instead of localized string for its Name parameter.

The scenario in which I use DisplayProperty is presented below. To show attribute property of the model property I use a converter with helper class like this:

```cs
namespace MyProject.Converters
{
    // helper class
    public class MetadataParameters
    {
        public Type ModelType { get; set; }
        public string ModelProperty { get; set; }
        public Type AttributeType { get; set; }
        public string AttributeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetadataConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var mp = parameter as MetadataParameters;
            var modelPropertyInfo = mp.ModelType.GetProperty(mp.ModelProperty);
            var attribute = modelPropertyInfo
                .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .Cast<Attribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault(memberInfo => memberInfo.GetType() == mp.AttributeType);
            var attributeProperty = attribute.GetType().GetProperty(mp.AttributeProperty);

            return attributeProperty.GetValue(attribute, null);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML resources:

```xml
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"
<converters:MetadataConverter x:Key="metadataConverter" />
```

XAML:

```xml
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"
xmlns:DataAnnotations="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;assembly=System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations"
xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:MyProject.Models"

<TextBlock 
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding
            Mode="OneWay"
            Converter="{StaticResource metadataConverter}">
            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                <converters:MetadataParameters
                    ModelType="{x:Type Models:Model}"
                    ModelProperty="ModelProperty"
                    AttributeType="{x:Type DataAnnotations:DisplayAttribute}"
                    AttributeProperty="Name" />                            
            </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

I write my own simple attribute, and it returns localized string instead of just the value of the name of the property (as DisplayAttribute does):

```cs
public class LocalizedDisplayAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string name;

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get
        {
            var rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(Resources.Strings));
            return rm.GetString(this.name);
        }
    }

    public LocalizedDisplayAttribute(string name)
        : base()
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


class MyModel
{
    [LocalizedDisplay("MyPropertyName")]
    public double MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

So why the DisplayAttribute doesn't localize its properties? MSDN says this attribute was designed for localization. And in my ASP.NET MVC project DisplayAttribute works properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are Get methods on the DisplayAttribute and a few others that you need to call, which will give you the localized string you're looking for. What you're doing here is to get the value of the DisplayAttribute.Name property, which is "MyPropertyName".

If you call DisplayAttribute.GetName(), it will look for the resource class as specified by ResourceType property, then it will use the Name property to reflect the property on the resource type.

I changed your code with the assumption that there will get a GetXXX() method for the AttributeProperty you request.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  var mp = parameter as MetadataParameters;
  var modelPropertyInfo = mp.ModelType.GetProperty(mp.ModelProperty);
  var attribute = modelPropertyInfo
      .GetCustomAttributes(true)
      .Cast<Attribute>()
      .FirstOrDefault(memberInfo => memberInfo.GetType() == mp.AttributeType);

  // We have to call the GetXXX methods on the attribute to get a localised result.
  //return ((DisplayAttribute)attribute).GetName();
  var result = attribute
    .GetType()
    .InvokeMember(
      "Get" + mp.AttributeProperty,
      BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
      null,
      attribute,
      new object[0]); 
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried you recipe and it works! Thanks. I just replaced the hardcoded string of the name of the invoked member to an [expression](http://code.google.com/p/gim-projects/source/browse/presentations/CantDanceTheLambda/src/MemberNameParser.cs) for convenience.

Comment: Thank you @base2 for pointing out the difference between .Name and .GetName. Now the localizations are being used.